# Razor in CSS/Less?

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a view where I create a container and populate it with some stuff.  the container name is passed to the view, so my controller sort of looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(string Container = "Products")
{
    ViewBag.Container = Container;
    return PartialView();
}
```

which then I call from within another view like this:

```
@Html.Action("Index", "Product", new { Container = "LatestProducts" })
```

the view includes its CSS and Javascript on the same page, like this:

```
<div id="@ViewBag.Container">
  <div class="New"></div>
  <ul></ul>
</div>

<style>
#@ViewBag.Container {
  ...
}
</style>
<script>
    function AddProduct(container, o) {
        var ul = $(container).find('ul');
        ul.append(o.whatever);
    }
    $(function() {
        @foreach (var item in Model) {
           @: AddProduct('#@ViewBag.Container', { whatever: item.whatever });
        }
    });
</script>
```

my problem is that now I'm ripping out all the Javascript/Css out of the page to put it into its own files, and I don't know how to get Razor to write the necessary container names...

thoughts anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this article [Dynamic Stylesheets Using Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10279873/dynamic-stylesheets-using-razor) suggests an awesome solution to the problem.  it leaves me with the question of how to support Less though, but that answer may come

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite see the point of your javascript. All that this javascript does is that it subscribes for the DOM ready event, finds the div with the specified id, then the ul inside it and then loops through the model and adds some property to it. Why don't you generate the markup directly on the server? It will be so much easier:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyViewModel>
<div id="@ViewBag.Container">
    <div class="New"></div>
    <ul>
        @Html.DisplayForModel()
    </ul>
</div>
```

and in the corresponding display template (`~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/MyViewModel.cshtml`):

```
@model MyViewModel
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Whatever)
```

As far as the CSS is concerned, you could include all possible styles in your separate CSS file which will be served and cached only once on client browsers. So even if it will be larger, it will be faster than using dynamic rules.

Comment: I generate calls to a javascript function to add stuff to the list instead of adding stuff to the list directly because the function is also called by ajax calls elsewhere, so it presents a uniform interface for adding to the list

Answer (score 0):

Use [RazorJS](http://john.katsiotis.com/blog/razorjs---write-razor-inside-your-javascript-files).

Comment: trying to figure out if it can be used for CSS.  I also have the issue that I don't want to hard-code paths in `background-image: url(...)`